# What is address allocation of memory register?

Tags: memory, microprocessor

What is ment by address allocation of memory register in microprocessor and memory topic or in computer architecture?

Memory chips are have no processing elements(passive elements). How memory chips are getting address allocation that selects a specific memory location.

Comment: Can you show a context, somewhere this is mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean "address allocation of memory *mapped* registers".

Those are hardware registers mapped into physical/virtual memory space, and thus need to have an `address`.